# Muse background height is too short - how to adjust?

Tags: adobe-muse

I've created a new Muse project, and I have adjusted the minimum height to a large area to ensure it will cover all screen resolutions, i.e.

[image]

However, when I preview or export to HTML, the background colour I've set only covers about 60% of the view, i.e.

[image]

I'm a Muse newbie. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I realised I just had to look at the other breakpoints, then adjust the height for those, i.e.

[image]